# Which is the parent class of Java.util.Map interface?

Tags: java, collections, interface

I searched for an answer but couldn't find one. Does any body know which clss is the parent class of `java.util.Map` interface is?

Is the `Object`  class a parent class of java.util.Map interface?

Comment: *"I searched in internet"* You shouldn't need to search far, but instead go straight to the official javadoc of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). It doesn't show any superinterfaces, because *there aren't any*. In contrast, just so you can see what it looks like, an interface like [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) shows two superinterfaces: `Collection`, `Iterable`.

Comment: A class can't be a supertype of an interface.

Answer (score 4):

`Map` is an interface, and an interface can only have a parent interface, not a parent class.

In the case of `java.util.Map`, it has no parent interface.

> Or else Object class is a parent class of java.util.Map interface?

No. Though any class that implements the `Map` interface will have the `Object` class as one of its ancestors (since `Object` class is the root class in the hierarchy of all classes).

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are not classes so the `Map` interface does not have a parent class.

Interfaces may have a parent interface but `Map` does not. Check out the docs and you will see that is has no parent interface. [Map Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)